How to properly switch between environments using Dio?
I have a specific task that require Dio reinitialization. I'm trying to switch between few environments dynamically (QA/DEV/PRODUCTION) by changing the baseUrl so I need to re-init services generated by retrofit and Dio as well. What I found that Dio has a method close that can break the current ongoing requests, so I tried to use it. But when I try to call some request even with new Dio object, I'm facing with the next error :

Error: Bad state: Can't establish connection after the adapter was closed."

I tried to pass the adapter, but result is the same.
Does anyone faced the same problem?
